# Get-ChildItem -Exclude returning Fullname instead of short name

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm having a strange issue when I run a Get-ChildItem -Exclude.

I've been using the following command at both source and destination locations to create an array of files after I've run a copy and then comparing the 2 directories.  It has been working just fine. (I was going to post images, but don't have a high enough reputation)

```
$sourcefiles = @(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path e:\Home\o365.test)
```

When I run this command, the array populates with the short name of the files.

I excluded PST files from the file copy and I needed to also exclude them in the compare, so I added an exclude to the GCI command.

```
$sourcefiles = @(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path e:\Home\o365.test -Exclude *.pst)
```

This returns all of the correct files (*.pst is in fact excluded), however it is returning the fullname of the files, rather than the shortname that I always got returned before.

This is causing the compare-object to fail, since the destination GCI doesn't have the exclude (Not needed since *.pst was excluded from the copy).  Besides, it is a UNC path and the fullname wouldn't match anyway.

I realize I could use split-path -leaf (which I've tried - and seems to work)

```
$sourcefiles = @(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path e:\Home\o365.test -Exclude *.pst | Split-Path -Leaf)
```

But I still don't understand why adding the -exclude param to GCI causes it to change the format of what it returns.

Does anyone have any insight into why this would be happening?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: For those, like me, who arrived here after searching for "short name", the OP appears to be using "short name" to mean the file's name within its directory ("file name") and "long name" to mean the full path specification ("file path"). The term "short name" is typically used to refer to the DOS compatible 8.3 alternate file name that can be linked to the same file (or directory) on some file systems (e.g. always on FAT32 and on NTFS unless the disable8dot3 flag is set when the file is created).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can't replicate what you're seeing here.  Placing an at sign before an operation in PowerShell is in fact the array operator, put simply putting it before a parenthesis with an operation doesn't return single properties like you're describing.

Now, you can make this happen if you place a property name on the back of the parenthesis to select just one property.  For example:

```
$files = @(Get-ChildItem -path c:\temp).BaseName
>LZelda.csv
>msvcr100.dll
>names-0.txt
>names-1.txt
>NOBGW00017.log
>nslookup.exe
>PolicySpy.exe
```

Adding the -Exclude parenthesis doesn't change the output at all.

```
$files = @(Get-ChildItem -path c:\temp -exclude *.png)
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        3/18/2015   2:34 PM                Android
da----        9/10/2013   7:17 PM                Bootfiles
d-----       12/13/2014   4:29 PM                camera
d-----         1/6/2015  11:49 AM                CFS
d-----       12/11/2014   1:08 PM                ebay
d-----         2/2/2014   1:55 PM                Finance
```

My reason for showing you this is that the things we get back are still FileSystem objects.  The only way to reduce $files down to containing just one property, like the FullName, BaseName or whatever is in the following two methods:

```
$files = @(Get-ChildItem -path c:\temp -exclude *.png).BaseName
$files = @(Get-ChildItem -path c:\temp -exclude *.png | Select -Expand BaseName)
```

Both will give the same output.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Fox.  I realized that I was creating an array.  I was actually looking to compare the objects, not just the names. The problem came on just the one property though - the name of the item, but since the name was different in each case, it failed the compare.

Comment: Perhaps you meant the "name" property. The "basename" (script property) is the name with any extension removed. Thus the first example should be a list of files with the extensions (.csv, .dll, .txt, .log, .exe) removed. (Unless there was a further extension after these which was removed.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is a deliberate "bug" (as I call it) introduced right from the start of Powershell (or at least from PS2.0). In order to ease the transition from `cmd` to Powershell, `Get-ChildItem` was given the alias `dir` and was then made to work like the `cmd` version of `dir` (as far as necessary to give a similar looking output). As with `cmd`,

```
PS > dir <directory path>
```

produces a listing of <directory path> (when simply displayed). In both cases (`cmd` and Powershell), an absent directory path uses . (the current directory). However, if the `cmd` version is invoked using a file name or wildcard pattern after the directory path (again, implicit . if no directory path) then the output is the matching file(s) (and directories for the wildcard case) in that directory (if any). `Get-ChildItem` does the same so that the alias, `dir`, gives similar output. It might have been expected that `Get-ChildItem`, when provided a wildcard path, would return a list of the **children** of any directories matching that wildcard path and ignore any matching files. If the argument were a plain file name, `Get-ChildItem` would complain that the argument provided cannot have children (as opposed to an empty directory which *can* have children but just doesn't). After all, if you want to match files or directories themselves (rather than their contents), you'd use `Get-Item`. Indeed, the results returned by `Get-ChildItem` in the case of file arguments and wildcards are identical to the equivalent `Get-Item`. However, the results returned by `Get-ChildItem` for actual children of a specified directory path differ slightly from those of `Get-Item`. Specifically, they have different `ToString()` methods (even though they both return FileInfo or DirectoryInfo objects). This means that converting the object to a string either by explicitly invoking `ToString()` or by using the returned object in an expression that requires a string, e.g.

```
PS > dir | foreach { "$_" }
```

gives different results.
Demonstration,

```
PS > gci C:\Windows\Web\Screen | foreach { "$_" }
img100.jpg
img101.png
img102.jpg
img103.png
img104.jpg
img105.jpg
PS > gci C:\Windows\web\screen\* | foreach { "$_" }
C:\Windows\web\screen\img100.jpg # note: uses argument path case.
C:\Windows\web\screen\img101.png # actual directory path case is
C:\Windows\web\screen\img102.jpg # C:\WINDOWS\Web\Screen
C:\Windows\web\screen\img103.png
C:\Windows\web\screen\img104.jpg
C:\Windows\web\screen\img105.jpg
PS > gi C:\Windows\Web\screen\* | foreach { "$_" }
C:\Windows\Web\screen\img100.jpg
C:\Windows\Web\screen\img101.png
C:\Windows\Web\screen\img102.jpg
C:\Windows\Web\screen\img103.png
C:\Windows\Web\screen\img104.jpg
C:\Windows\Web\screen\img105.jpg
PS > gci C:\Windows\Web\screen\img100.jpg | foreach { "$_" }
C:\Windows\Web\screen\img100.jpg
PS > gi C:\Windows\Web\screen\img100.jpg | foreach { "$_" }
C:\Windows\Web\screen\img100.jpg
```

Thus, I suspect that the OP is using implicit string conversion to get the "name" of the file and running foul of this "bug" which apparently also manifests when `-Exclude` is used (independent of `-Recurse` which has no effect). The solution is to not rely on string conversion and use the actual string properties, either name or fullname (whichever is needed).

```
PS > gci C:\Windows\Web\Screen | foreach { "$($_.fullname)" }
C:\Windows\Web\screen\img100.jpg
C:\Windows\Web\screen\img101.png
C:\Windows\Web\screen\img102.jpg
C:\Windows\Web\screen\img103.png
C:\Windows\Web\screen\img104.jpg
C:\Windows\Web\screen\img105.jpg
PS > gci C:\Windows\web\screen\* | foreach { "$($_.name)" }
img100.jpg
img101.png
img102.jpg
img103.png
img104.jpg
img105.jpg
```

An alternate (long term) solution could be to fix `Get-ChildItem` so that `ToString()` always returned the same result. This might be considered a breaking change but I suspect this "bug" has tripped up many users, even those who are already aware of it. I know I keep forgetting. Could even have `Get-Item` and `Get-ChildItem` use the same `ToString()`, whichever that is.

For a radical (and likely inferno inducing) solution, "fix" `Get-ChildItem` to only return children (or errors) and make `dir` a function that invoked `Get-ChildItem` or `Get-Item` as required. This would then restore the Powershell ethos of "cmdlets do what their name says they do" instead of having `Get-ChildItem` sometimes return children and sometimes items. (Way too much of a breaking change so not holding my breath for that one.)

Test performed using PS 5.1.18362.145.